# Access a queryset's 'values_list' in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to access the `values_list` of a query_set in a template.

In a view I have used the following if statement to determine whether an `Outcome` (model) exists for a given `Participant` (model):

```
if not form.cleaned_data['timepoint'] in patient.outcome_set.values_list('timepoint', flat=True):
```

This worked perfectly - now I want to be able to do something similar with the `values_list` in a template. However, when I try to limit the `values_list` to just the `timepoint` variable on the model, it throws a `TemplateSyntaxError` `Could not parse the remainder: '('template')' from 'patient.outcome_set.values_list('template')'`

If I print the `values_list` to the screen using `{{ patient.outcome_set.values_list }}` it prints all the values of each outcome fine, but I can't work out how to limit the values_list to just the timepoint variable.

Current template:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Patient</th>
      <th>Baseline</th>
      <th>Follow-up</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {% for patient in patients %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ patient.name }}</td>

        {% if 'baseline' in patient.outcome_set.values_list('timepoint') %}
          <td>INSERT TICK</td>
        {% else %}
          <td>INSERT CROSS</td>
        {% endif %}

        {% if 'followup' in patient.outcome_set.values_list('timepoint') %}
          <td>INSERT TICK</td>
        {% else %}
          <td>INSERT CROSS</td>
        {% endif %}

      </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Though this kind of logic is more suited in views, you can use a [custom template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-template-tags/) for this. Something like below.

```
# extra_tags.py

@register.filter
def get_value_in_qs(queryset, key):
    return queryset.values(key, flat=True)
```

Then you can use it in your template in this way:

```
{% load extra_tags %}
...
    {% for patient in patients %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ patient.name }}</td>

        {% if 'baseline' in patient.outcome_set|get_value_in_qs:'timepoint' %}
# or for better readability use a with tag
{% with patient_timepoint=patient.outcome_set|get_value_in_qs:'timepoint' %}
{% if 'baseline' in patient_timepoint %} ...



....
```